# How can I show "space" as "-" or other marks in gEdit?

Tags: linux, gedit

How can I show "space" as "-" or other marks in gEdit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the [gEdit plugin](http://live.gnome.org/GeditPlugins) "Draw Spaces" has this functionality.